# Замена 1 бита в числе. Задача

Tags: java

Реализуйте метод `flipBit`, изменяющий значение одного бита заданного целого числа на противоположное.
Договоримся, что биты нумеруются от младшего (индекс 1) к старшему (индекс 32).

```
public static int flipBit(int value, int bitIndex) {
    char[] mass = Integer.toBinaryString(value).toCharArray();
    int index = bitIndex%32;
        if(mass[index - 1] == '0') mass[index - 1] = '1';
        else mass[index - 1] = '0';
        return Integer.parseInt(new String(mass), 2);
}
```

Выдает ошибку:

> Failed test #3. Run time error:
>  Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 30
>   at
>   Main.flipBit(Main.java:27)
>     at Main.main(Main.java:14)
>   at
>   Main.main(Main.java:7)

Comment: Я конечно Java не знаю, но не проще ли как-то так: `value^(1<<(bitIndex-1))`?

Comment: давайте сразу `String.format("%32s", Integer.toBinaryString( value ) ).replace(' ', '0')`, чо там :)

Comment: Задача с курса stepik.org по Java?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Чтобы инвертировать бит на определенной позиции, нужно сдвинуть 1 на желаемое число позиций влево (это будет маска), и затем сделать XOR с исходным числом.

```
public static long flipBit(int position, long value) {
    return value ^ 1 << position;
}
```

Либо, можно воспользоваться классом [BitSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

```
public static long flipBit(int position, long value) {
    BitSet bs = BitSet.valueOf(new long[] { value });
    bs.flip(position);
    return bs.toLongArray()[0];
}
```

Биты нумеруются начиная с 0, справа налево.

```
long value = 10L;
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(value)); // 1010
System.out.println(Long.toBinaryString(flipBit(1, value))); // 1000
```

Дополнительные условия вашей задачи и проверку на допустимые значения добавьте самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо за BitSet

Answer (score 1):

Пошаговый примерчик, где: 
 a -изменяемое число.
 b -номер бита который меняем в изменяемом числе.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 15;
    int b = 3;
    // т.к. биты нумеруются не с нуля, а с еденеицы;
    b--;
    // вводим еще одну нулевую переменную, чтобы получить маску с измененным битом в ней.
    int c = 0;
    System.out.println( " двоичный вид " + c + ": " +Integer.toString(c, 2)); // 0  : 0
    // сдвигаем битовую еденицу на нужное значение и получаем маску.
    c = 1 << b;
    System.out.println( " двоичный вид " + c + ": " +Integer.toString(c, 2)); // 4  : 100
    // отобразим битовое значение числа, в котором будем изменять нужный бит.
    System.out.println( " двоичный вид " + a + ": " +Integer.toString(a, 2)); // 15 : 1111
    // выполняем операцию XOR между маской и изменяемым числом
    a = a ^ c;
    System.out.println( " двоичный вид " + a + ": " +Integer.toString(a, 2)); // 11 : 1011
}
```