# Java дополнительные функции

Tags: java

Всем добрый день. Подскажите, как можно реализовать эту задачу?
Вводится исходное число A и число x. Вывести число А, x-ый бит которого равен 1

```
import java.util.*;
public class Program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = in.nextInt(), i = in.nextInt();
        System.out.println(5 | 7);

    }

}
```

Возникает вопрос, как обращаться к элементу именно x-ой позиции без индекса, а просто с побитовыми операциями?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Замена 1 бита в числе. Задача](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/491216/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-1-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5-%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = in.nextInt(), i = in.nextInt();
System.out.println(x | (1 << i));
```

```
x = 0b101
1 << i = 0b010
0b101 | 0b010 = 0b111
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin ну ок, поправил, не знаю что ещё тут добавить

Comment: @timur, скажите, 1 << i - значит мы единицу смещаем влево и прибавляем 1(если i == 1) и получается 11. а уже с помощью | от пятерки (101) смотрим: 1 на 1 дает 1, 0 на 1 дает 1, 1 на 0 дает 1. И получается 111. Такая теория верна?

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
int numberOfRazr = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
if((number << numberOfRazr) % 2 == 0) {
    System.out.println((int) (number + Math.pow(2, numberOfRazr - 1)));
} else {
    System.out.println(number);
}
```

Тест:

```
10
3
14
```

Сначала узнаем, есть ли на этом разряде двоичного числа единицы. Потом, если нет, добавляем двоичное число 1(нули, число которых равно `numberOfRazr`)